# App Engine URLFetch service called from Clojure gives AccessControlException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, clojure

I'm trying to build a simple web widget in Clojure which should fetch a Picasa feed, retrieve the thumbnail URLs from there, and return HTML which will be inserted into a page (using JQuery AJAX call). The Picasa feed has a https://... url.
Everything works when I run it in a local Jetty instance using mvn jetty:run ; however when I try to run in a local GAE instance (mvn gae:run) it fails with an AccessControlException.
I've read the GAE documentation, but this states that for URLFetch from Java one should just use the normal Java URLConnection class where Google will provide their own implementation. As far as I can see I'm following their example to the letter, only using Clojure/Java interop.

Google example code looks like this:

```
import java.net.URL;
// (other imports omitted)
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/atom.xml");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // ...
    }
```

Interestingly this is calling openStream directly on the URL although elsewhere the documentation mentions to use UrlConnection. I've tried both, but the result is the same.
My corresponding Clojure code, using openConnection:

```
  (if (.startsWith str-url "https://picasaweb.google.com")
    (let [feed-url (java.net.URL. str-url)
          connection (.openConnection feed-url)
          xmltags (xml-seq (parse (.openStream connection)))]
  ; ...
```

When I run this in GAE I get the following stack trace (truncated)

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
```

And finally at the bottom:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied     (java.security.SecurityPermission getProperty.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:252)
    at java.security.Security.getProperty(Security.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.<clinit>(SslContextFactory.java:92)
    ... 74 more
```

I have been Googling to see if there is any setting I should add in appengine-web.xml or somewhere else, but I see nothing. Everything I read tells me this should "just work", but it doesn't.
Any advice is most welcome; I can post full source or a full stacktrace if desired, although I think the above is pretty much the pertinent bits.

Answer (score 0):

[`openStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) is shorthand for `openConnection().getInputStream()`, where `openConnection()` returns `URLConnection`.